# Website Building throught the Terminal Linux MInt please help!

Tags: linux-mint

So! I'm not even 13- 11 to be exact. But I'm making a Game, so, of course, I should have a Website, that would make sense. And, I'm making It from scratch and! I need to learn things. I'm using a ssh Web server and have lots of questions. I'm using php but I can't seem to find any Videos on Youtube, and I've tried looking It up on Google, which Is how I found this. One major thing before I pay some money to publish the thing Is Tabs. How this Website has /questiond /tag /users, etc, I want to know how to do that. If you want I can make a short video of what I've done so far. If you've made a Website from scratch using the Terminal I would really like to know how to do a lot more things. I have Linux Mint, the KDE Desktop.

Comment: What is your actual question?

Comment: You are asking for a lot of disparate, albeit tangentially related, information. This site is not the appropriate vehicle for this sort of question (see [what questions not to ask](http://unix.stackexchange.com/faq#dontask) for details). You are better off looking for a basic primer on building websites and then asking *specific* questions about issues that you encounter.

Answer (score 1):

Install Netbeans with php support and you solver all y our problems. You can connect via sftp and develop webpage peacefully.

If you don't like that approach and you want more bash involved, look for "vim as php IDE". Perhaps here: http://www.koch.ro/blog/index.php?/archives/63-VIM-as-a-PHP-IDE.html